# Can I make process every bean member's code more beautiful?

Tags: java

I have  a class:Data,a calss: Alarm .
 I must statistics data then output excel use npoi.Alarm may be null.
now is my code:

```
 while (it.hasNext()){       
             Data t =  it.next(); 
             row = sheet.createRow(index++);
             Alarm a=alarms.get(t.getDeviceid().trim());
              cell = row.createCell(0);
             if(a==null||inRange(t.getNoise(),a.getNoiselow(),a.getNoiseup()))
                     cell.setCellStyle(styleNormal);
             else
                 cell.setCellStyle(styleError);
             cell.setCellValue((double)t.getNoise());
             cell = row.createCell(1);
             if(a==null||inRange(t.getPm(),a.getPmlow(),a.getPmup()))
                     cell.setCellStyle(styleNormal);
             else
                 cell.setCellStyle(styleError);
             cell.setCellValue((double)t.getPm());
             cell = row.createCell(2);
             if(a==null||inRange(t.getPressure(),a.getPressurelow(),a.getPressureup()))
                     cell.setCellStyle(styleNormal);
             else
                 cell.setCellStyle(styleError);
             cell.setCellValue((double)t.getPressure());
        ....
```

I repeat every bean property.... can I improve such code?

Comment: `a == null || ...` is really perturbing. Why did you prefer that over `a != null && ...` ?

Comment: Are you allowed to change `Data` and `Alarm` ?

Comment: no,Data and Alarm only read,many property.noise...pm...windspeed....@Spotted

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to start: **Find repetitive code and put that in a method.**

```
  cell = row.createCell(0);
  if(a==null||inRange(t.getNoise(),a.getNoiselow(),a.getNoiseup()))
      cell.setCellStyle(styleNormal);
  else
      cell.setCellStyle(styleError);
  cell.setCellValue((double)t.getNoise());
```

You can put above code in method and call from within `while` loop:

```
 private void setCell(Row row, Data data, int cellIndex)
 {
      cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
      Alarm a=alarms.get(data.getDeviceid().trim());
      if(a==null||inRange(data, a, cellIndex))
          cell.setCellStyle(styleNormal);
      else
          cell.setCellStyle(styleError);

      // You can also do as below if you can read it easily!!
      // cell.setCellStyle(a==null||inRange(data, a, cellIndex)?styleNormal:styleError);

      // This switch-case should also be moved to separate method.
      // Leaving that to you. 
      switch(cellIndex)
      {
          case 0:  cell.setCellValue((double)data.getNoise()); break;
          case 1:  cell.setCellValue((double)t.getPm()); break;
          ...
          ...
          default: /*set default value and break or throw InvalidCellIndex exception*/
      }
 }

 private boolean inRange(Date data, Alarm a, int cellIndex)
 {
      switch(cellIndex)
      {
          case 0:  return inRange(data.getNoise(),a.getNoiselow(),a.getNoiseup();
          case 1:  return inRange(data.getPm(),a.getPmlow(),a.getPmup();
          ...
          ...
          default: /* throw InvalidCellIndex exception*/
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Azodious that repetitive code should be abstracted in methods, but I would handle it slightly differently:

```
while (it.hasNext()){       
    Data t =  it.next(); 
    row = sheet.createRow(index++);
    Alarm a=alarms.get(t.getDeviceid().trim());
    setNoise(row, 0, t, a);
    setPm(row, 1, t, a);
    ...
}

private void setCellValue(Row row, int cellIndex, double value, boolean error) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
    if (error) {
        cell.setCellStyle(styleError);
    } else {
        cell.setCellStyle(styleNormal);
    }
    cell.setCellValue(value);
}

private void setNoise(Row row, int cellIndex, Data t, Alarm a) {
    setCellValue(row, cellIndex, data.getNoise(),
        a == null || inRange(t.getNoise(),a.getNoiselow(),a.getNoiseup()));
}

...
```